# how to take only JSON response from SOAPUI

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

I am working on project which is giving XML and JSON type of response. I need to take only JSON response from SOAPUI to process for next step.

Is there any SOAPUI api available to get only JSON type of response by groovy script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this response [SoapUI Groovy Script’s JSON Responses Is Empty When Using Testrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784152/soapui-groovy-script-s-json-resones-is-empty-when-using-testrunner/32789547#32789547)

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
//provide the correct rest test step name
def stepName='testStepForPing'
def step = context.testCase.getTestStepByName(stepName)
def response = new String(step.testRequest.messageExchange.response.responseContent)
log.info response
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a REST service, by default this approach will fetch the response in JSON format.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def response = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("RequestStepName#Response")
// as a string -> def response = context.expand('${RequestStepName#Response}')
```

You can get it as xml using #ResponseAsXml.

Answer (score 0):

In the SOAPUI Javascript context I developed this algorithm.

```
var xmlHolder = com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContent);
var nodes = xmlHolder.getDomNodes("//SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns:xxxxxx");

var obj = {};

toJsonObject(nodes[0], obj);

function toJsonObject(xmlObject, jsonObject) {
    for (var i = 0; i < xmlObject.getLength(); i++) {
        var node = xmlObject.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == org.w3c.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if (node.getLength() == 1) {
                if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                    jsonObject[node.getNodeName()] = String(node.item(0).getNodeValue());
                }
            } else {
                if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                    jsonObject[node.getNodeName()] = {};
                    jsonObject[node.getNodeName()] = toJsonObject(node, jsonObject[node.getNodeName()]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return jsonObject;
}

log.info(JSON.stringify(obj));
context.setProperty('JSON: ', JSON.stringify(obj));
```